# NORMAL label in top right of some applications

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I've managed to get a label saying "NORMAL" in top right corner of certain applications. How do I get rid of it?

Example Spotify:

[image: screenshot of Spotify showing this NORMAL label]

Comment: If you mess up, you better reinstall. Although someone with good skills may salvage a system, it may become quite technical.

Comment: That's really not useful feedback, @vanadium. I'm looking to learn how to troubleshoot my way through resolving issues in Linux, so it might actually be a option to use for a stable development environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: screenshot of option that caused this]
Disable this setting, and it's gone. Think a reboot is required as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm was facing the same issue, not sure what actually triggered it. I'm using KDE with a Nvidia 2070 on driver 440.31

I fixed it, but I don't know how. I did several things at once:

- I messed with the Display settings in KDE.
- Moved the scaling option
- Enabled my laptop screen and disabled it.
- In my nvidia settings I made sure any displaying of G-SYNC or graphics API labelling was unchecked.

I basically changed the settings and changed them back to hopefully have those settings reapplied. Then I restarted and I don't see the label any more.

The restart might be the most important part.

Comment: Actually when thinking about it, I was using an older version of the Nvidia drivers, and then upgraded to 440 as well. Might be that to be honest. Unfortunately no time to test this right now, but definitely will take a look when I get time.

Comment: I answered my own question and found the solution.