# My electron Apps show "NORMAL" in top right

Tags: nvidia, 20.10, spotify, visual-studio-code, electron

I use some electron apps, like every body, and i have a pixel "NORMAL" on top right corner of some of Apps, and inside menu of menubar.

Screens of apps with NORMAL:

- [Ferdi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xSUZ.png)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Rgm.png)
- [Spotify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLXLM.png)

I start an Electron Apps project last year (for testing), so i have some electron dependences for development. I have Electron Fiddle.

Electron Fiddle is a Electron Apps and he doesn't have "NORMAL", same for the default hello world apps of Electron Fiddle.

Screens of apps without NORMAL:

- [Electron Fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0RQG.png)
- [Hello world Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og7E3.png)

Some info about my env:

- Ubuntu 20.10
- GNOME 3.38.1
- X11

I use same apps on Windows 10, and didn't have any "normal".

Any idea ?

### ANSWER:

@RayWu said in [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301126/my-electron-apps-show-normal-in-top-left#comment2211733_1301126) :

> Spotify is not an electron app, it is a CEF app. Do you have any kind of GPU overlay enabled?

After this I look for NVIDIA Settings displaying "normal" and found this **[answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194754/242472)**

Works for me, this is fixed, thanks :)

Comment: Spotify is not an electron app, it is a CEF app. Do you have any kind of GPU overlay enabled?

Comment: @RayWu Ok for spotify, i didn't know. And for the GPU overlay, i don't think. I'm using nvidia driver (nvidia-driver-455) with NVIDIA X Server Settings (nvidia-settings). i chack inside NVIDIA Settings, i didn't see anythink about overlay or any "NORMAL" settings.